# Maven deploy to nexus certificate issues

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, certificate, nexus

After moving my nexus server from a home server to a root server, I get the following error if I start any build job on my jenkins slave:

*Error transferring file: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target*

I had no certificate at home and now I'm using a certificate that is signed by startssl and not a self signed one.

After reading up on google, I found that there was some trouble with the maven 3.0.5 update and that you need to import your certificate to the java certificate file. I also read that this is only necessary if you are using a self signed certificate but I still tried this solution and it didn't help. I did so by directly importing my certificates and by using the class from this link and then copying the created file:

https://www.liferay.com/de/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/fixing-suncertpathbuilderexception-caused-by-maven-downloading-from-self-signed-repository

The next thing I tried was copying the certificate file from a windows machine which was reported to help in some cases, but nothing.

I then started the build with different maven versions, 3.0.1, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.2.1, it didn't matter. It's always the same.

As a last step I upgraded my java from openjdk 7 to oracle java 7 and 8 which was also a dead end.

Has anyone the key information that I'm missing here? I don't want to add the properties to ignore any certificate checks. This has to work in a way that is secure and reliable.

Edit: doing the release manually via console works just fine. It seems that the tomcat/jenkins has some trouble with the certificate resolution. I also tried this:

https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029

There are no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

I just found why it did not work. I configured jenkins to use an automatically installed JDK for the build jobs. The problem is, this installation does not get any of the environment variables I set for the VM that is actually running the tomcat/jenkins server, which is reasonable on second thought but hardly transparent. I couldn't find a method to set any environment variables for the VM so this is not a solution.

What I did to resolve it was quite easy, use the VM that actually starts the tomcat/jenkins server and which is configured with my certificates.